# Using TypeScript with Jest not catching syntax errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

When compiling typescript back to js, you can specify the option `--alwaysStrict` which:

> Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file

So, if you are missing a compulsory parameter in a function, it gets caught by this strict mode.

We are using `ts-jest` so we can use Jest to test our Typescript code. The problem we face is that we have not found a way to mimic the strict parsing behaviour.

This is really annoying because all the test seem to pass, but from time to time there is a syntactic mistake that slips through the cracks and we only notice when we are creating the production build (where we set the `--alwaysStrict`)

In our `jest.config.js` we have:

````
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  "testEnvironment": "node"
};```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts-jest` uses the `tsconfig.json` from your project by default.

(Note: if you want a separate config file for your tests you can [configure `ts-jest` to use a different config file](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/tsconfig))

You can set `alwaysStrict` in the `compilerOptions` section of [the config file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and `ts-jest` use that flag when compiling your TypeScript.

Comment: BTW apart from ```alwaysStrict``` I've needed to add the option ```diagnostics```set to ```true``` as well to make sure the tests break

Answer (score 0):

The only configuration option that enabled me to start seeing compiler errors when running tests is the following:

`jest.config.ts`:

```
{
   // ...
   transform: {
    // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
    // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        tsconfig: 'tests/tsconfig.json',
        diagnostics: {
          warnOnly: true, // <- This is the key
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Using any configuration which requires a custom `tsconfig.json` for testing, without specifying: [`diagnostics: { warnOnly: true }`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/diagnostics#do-not-fail-on-first-error), will simply lead to jest silently failing tests without giving us even a clue as to what is happening. Not even simply `diagnostics: true` will work.

Even with the above option, you may or may not see those diagnostics warnings if you have enabled `cache` in jest config. Some solutions for this:

1. Disable cache in jest config by setting the `cache` key to `false`.
2. Clear jest cache before running your test by first doing `jest --clearCache`.

See also the [`exclude`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/diagnostics/#enabling-diagnostics-for-test-files-only) option which allows you to disable error-reporting for all non-test files.